# Git installation issue(windows 7 ,64 bit)

Tags: git

I have joined HTML,CSS3 and java script(Johns Hopkins University) course on course era.

When trying to install Git as instructed in video i got following error

[image]

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not due to corrupt setup file as suggested by some people.Main problem was due to Avast antivirus which was marking the file as threat.To overcome this just disable the antivirus during installation and you can get over the Code 2 error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your installation file is corrupted, download and install it again.

If you still get this error delete the git folder under your program file and then re-install it.

Comment: I already tried option 1 it didn't work, and their is no git folder in my program file.Thanks for your time:)